# How to get AJAX to load page at top of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My site contains a div where different pages are loaded using ajax.  On a button click, a new page can be loaded and the pages always appear in that div.

The problem is if I go to a new page and scroll down without scrolling back to the top of that page, new pages will load at the same position below the top of the page, not at the top of the page.  I want to force all pages to load at the top.

Here are the relevant page elements:

The div (where the page content goes):

```
<div class="main_text">
<div id="C2"><span style="color:black">MTX</span></div>
</div>
```

The button:

```
<div class="C1"><br><button class="button_01" id="btn07" onclick="HideDropdown(); ShowAjax(7);">Page 7</button></div>
```

The AJAX code:

```
<script>
function ShowPage(type) {
    var filename = "page_" + type + ".htm"
    $( "#C2" ).hide().load( filename ).fadeIn(500);
}
</script>
```

The most important line is:

```
$( "#C2" ).hide().load( filename ).fadeIn(500);
```

At the top of each page I have:

```
<div id="bkmk00"></div>
```

I want to open each page at the top of the page (at "bkmk00).  I saw a post that said I could add an id name and it would load the page at that ID:

```
$( "#C2" ).hide().load( filename "bkmk00" ).fadeIn(500);
```

but with that, it doesn't load anything.  Instead, the Firefox 67 dev console says "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" for this ajax function call, and it points to character 37 which is right after filename.  That looks like I can't add the second parameter "bkmk00."

My question is, how can I get the page to load at "bkmk00" at the top of the page to be loaded?

Comment: Your missing the line termination after ".htm";

Comment: @IMustBeSomeone - the ajax call is above, between the <script> tags.  Are you looking for something else?  That is the call I use to load all pages, but I need something to tell it to load all pages at top of page.

Comment: filename "bkmk00", you are missing the "#bkmk00"

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function ShowPage(type) {
    var filename = "page_" + type + ".htm"
    $( "#C2" ).hide().load( filename ).fadeIn(500);
}
</script>
```

You are close but not quite, load function has 2 parameters, input file and a function callback:

```
var filename = "page_" + type + ".htm"
$( "#C2" ).hide()
$( "#bkmk00" ).load(filename, function(){
    $( "#bkmk00" ).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: The function as is now works, but it doesn't load at top of page.  What you show only makes the fadeIn part of a separate function.  My question is:  how do I get it to load at the top of the page?  What you show doesn't appear to do that unless I'm missing something.

Comment: my bad, I put the wrong id on the inside of the function, should work now.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying that now.

Comment: If you set up a jsfiddle we could help you better. Not knowing where the divs are makes it kind of hard.

Comment: My problem right now is that it works as I originally wrote it but doesn't load at the top.  I just replaced it with your code and it doesn't load pages.  FF dev console doesn't report any errors.  I can try Chrome to see if any errors are reported.

Comment: mm maybe I was loading the new info in the hidden div, try with the updated one

Comment: No, it wants to load into #C2.  Replacing that with "bkmk00" doesn't work .